# Query returns no results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a query that counts emails sent by customers, based on their subject.

```
    DECLARE @LastMonthNo varchar(2)
    DECLARE @LastMYear varchar(4)

    SET @LastMonthNo = DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m,-1,GetDate()))
    SET @LastMYear = DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(m,-1,GetDate()));

    SELECT 
        CustID, CustName, CustEmail,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN EmailSubject LIKE 'KeyWord' THEN 1 END),0) AS TotalEmail
    FROM 
        TableEmails
    WHERE 
        DATEPART(M, DATESENT) = @LastMonthNo
        AND DATEPART(YYYY, DATESENT) = @LastYearNo
GROUP BY CustID, CustName, CustEmail
```

For some customers, the query returns no results. I do not mean NULL, I mean there is no record at all. However, I need to identify those customers.

What can I do to get the query to generate some sort of results? A 0 would be perfect.

Comment: Show the rest of the query and give you table structure, sample data and expected output based on that.

Comment: The query returns results if I comment and exclude the line to sum records where keyword is in the subject.

If I run a differen query to scan the Emails table, there are no results. In other words, I get blank results when the customer has never sent any email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
    SELECT CustID, CustName, CustEmail,
        SUM(CASE WHEN EmailSubject LIKE 'KeyWord' 
                      AND DATEPART(YYYY,DATESENT)=@LastYearNo 
                      AND DATEPART(YYYY,DATESENT)=@LastYearNo  
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalEmail,
    FROM TableEmails
    GROUP BY CustID, CustName, CustEmail
```

**What is the difference?**

WHERE part executes before GROUP BY. So, with your query, you are grouping your results after other customers are filtered out. If you move that condition to CASE statement, you will check that condition on each record in the table regardless of dates. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I remove the ISNULL, I still get no results.

Comment: @DeepDiver it is not just removing ISNULL. Notice the GROUP BY in above answer.

Comment: @DarkNight, noticed it, thank you. And also present in the Query.
The problem occurs because there are no emails sent by a particular customer during the previous month. If I run the same query withouth the lines where I look at the sending period, then there are results because the customer sent some emails in 2013. 

I need to get around the situation with blank results, some how, if possible.

Comment: @DarkNight bingo! That works! And now I can add again the ISNULL to replace NULL with 0. What I do not get is why the previous version, with the DATEPARt in the WHERE clause would not work. The concept is the same.

Tnx a million for your help, appreciated!

Comment: It does answer my question and solves the issue. I also accepted it, tnx. What I miss is why that works and mine did not! Read your reply, it makes sense indeed. EVen though the query was actually running on 1 single customer. But yes, I do see the point. Tnx a million.